# How to make a zoom with two fingers in android?

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I would like to implement zoom, let's say ImageView with two fingers. The most important thing is that the ImageView increases to a point located between the fingers (let's say as a zoom of a picture in the gallery)

I have reviewed many articles on this topic. Many implement ScaleGestureDetector, but all these implementations increase the View to only one default point, which I can't change (Usually this zoom works just in the middle of the screen, ignoring where we start to zoom with our fingers). Also, all these articles are quite old and written in Java(I would like to see the implementation on Kotlin). I would like to know how this problem is being solved today

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Have you seen this guide: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/scale?hl=en#more-complex-scaling-example ?

Comment: Yes, I saw this guide. But most likely because of my inexperience I can't understand it. I tried to rewrite the code from this guide, but apart from the usual Scale, nothing works for me
@dev.bmax